# C++ flight booking program

Tags: c++, console

I am writing a program to allot seats in a flight.

**Code:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int i=0, j=0, seatNo;
int seatsAllotted=0;

//10 seats numbered 1 through 10
//0->seat unavailable
//1->seat available

int available[10];

for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    available[i]=1;
}

int choice;

while(1)
{

    cout<<"\n\n1. BOOKING";
    cout<<"\n";

    cout<<"2. CANCELLATION\n";
    cin>>choice;

    switch(choice)
    {

    //BOOKING PART

    case 1:

        int no;

        cout<<"\n\nEnter no. of seats to be booked: ";
        cin>>no;

        if((seatsAllotted+no)>10)
        {
            cout<<"Insufficient no. of seats are available";
        }

        else
        {

            for(j=1; j<=no; j++)
            {
                for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
                {
                    if(available[i]==1)
                    {
                        seatNo=i;
                        available[i]=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                cout<<"\nSeat nos. allotted are: ";
                cout<<seatNo;

                seatsAllotted+=1;
            }
        }
        break;

    //CANCELLATION PART
    case 2:

        int cancel;

        cout<<"\n\nEnter the seat nos. to be cancelled: ";
        cin>>cancel;

        available[cancel]=1;
        seatsAllotted-=1;

        break;

    default:

        cout<<"Wrong choice";

    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Normally the program outputs the seat nos. as desired.
But when I input certain values, same seat no. is allotted twice.

**Please see the image**

https://preview.ibb.co/knP3FQ/book.png

*When I gave 3 as input the output was correct.*
*But when I want to book 8 seats, the answer is incorrect.*

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I hope you are aware that your comment `//10 seats numbered 0 through 10` means 11 seats.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar Rai Yup. Sorry about that. I corrected that.

Comment: @DigitalRevenge your correction is wrong, you should run from i=0; i<=9 and not i=1; i<=10. Your array with 10 cells populates the 0-9 cells

Comment: @yakobom The problem's that seat nos. start with 1. If I loop it from 0, the first seat no. that is assigned is 0. I want the first seat assigned to be 1.

Comment: Then change your code so the seat number will be the cell in the array + 1. Your code is simply wrong - in your current code you are accessing a cell that does not exist (available[10]).

Comment: @yakobom The code's not wrong. You're saying me to run the loop from 0 through 9 (i.e 10 cells). In my code the loop runs from 1 through 10 (also 10 cells). In both cases, the loop populates 10 cells. available[10] does indeed exist. Check out: https://image.ibb.co/hYnFvQ/2.png

Comment: So you think the array index is meaningless? You could simply run from 1000 to 1010? available[10]  is indeed illegal.

Comment: @DigitalRevenge - you should probably refresh your basic c/c++. Declaring int available[10] means your have an array with cells 0-9. That is a fact...

Comment: @manni66 My bad. Reading your comment made me realize what my mistake was. We were taught in class that in C++, the lower bound of the array is always 0. And somehow I forgot that. Thanks ;)

Comment: @yakobom I guess I really have to go through the basics again. I was wrong, you were right. It just took me some time to realize that. Sorry for that. And thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in below lines:

```
for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    available[i]=1;
}
```

You have declared `int available[10]`. That means index can be from `0` to `9`,

Hence for loop should be 
`for(i=0; i<10; i++)`